# SQL query that sums and groups in a new column

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, case

I've got two tables with values that I would like to compare, but I haven't quite figured out how to get the code right.

These are the two tables I have:

**Table 1** (costs that run monthly)

```
id    amount     name     start                  end
1     500        Text 1   2013-09-01 00:00:00    2013-10-31 00:00:00
2     800        Text 2   2013-10-01 00:00:00    2013-10-31 00:00:00
3     200        Text 3   2013-09-01 00:00:00    2013-11-30 00:00:00
```

**Table 2** (invoices)

```
id    table1id   amount   month
51    1          100      201309
52    1          300      201309
53    1          500      201310
54    2          900      201310
55    3          300      201309
56    3          200      201310
57    3          250      201311
```

What I want is a table that looks like this:

```
Table1id name    SepTable2  SepTable1  OctTable2  OctTable1  NovTable2  NovTable1
1        Text 1  400        500        500        500
2        Text 2                        900        800
3        Text 3  300        200        200        200        250        200
```

So far I've managed to accomplish this:

```
Table1id   name    SepTable1  OctTable1  NovTable1
1          Text 1  500        500        500
2          Text 2             800
3          Text 3  200        200        200
```

With code that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
table1.id AS table1id,
table1.name,

case when table1.start < '2013-09-30 23:59:59' 
and table1.end > '2013-09-01 00:00:01'
then table1.amount
else '' end AS SepTable1,

case when table1.start < '2013-10-31 23:59:59' 
and table1.end > '2013-10-01 00:00:01'
then table1.amount
else '' end AS OctTable1,

case when table1.start < '2013-11-30 23:59:59' 
and table1.end > '2013-11-01 00:00:01'
then table1.amount
else '' end AS NovTable1

from Table1

INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.Table1id
```

What I need is a way to get the sums of all entries in Table2, where the Table1id is the same and where month is the same, to group and sum up and go into the right place in a new column... And I can't figure out how to get it right. I'm thinking that GROUP BY and SUM will be involved somehow, but I'm quite lost here and I've tried to google it for hours now without finding a good result (I might be using the wrong search strings).

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me solve this or just give me some kind of advice that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What about other years? You've added the column named `OctTable1` but should actually be `Oct2013Table1`, right? Then the amounts of columns will be dynamic

Comment: As of right now I only have six columns, so year isn't an issue yet and it saves a little space. I'm thinking that when time comes I'll just replace OctTable1 with Oct2013Table1 and so on. It's just two places per month so I think I'll be able to handle it. 

Thank you for taking the time to read my post and giving me that advice. I wish you a pleasant day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on your comment in which you don't care about the year this would get you the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN i.month = 201309 THEN
    COALESCE(i.amount, 0)
  END) SepInvoices,
  MAX(CASE WHEN c.start < '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND c.end >= '2013-09-01 00:00:00' THEN
    c.amount
  END) SepCosts
FROM costs c
LEFT JOIN invoices i ON c.id = i.costid
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

Of course, apply the same logic for the other months.

See the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/552f4/1).

Comment: Thankt a lot for taking the time and making the effort to write this! This is pretty much what I ended up doing, even though I used a bit simpler language as I am still learning some of the functions that you used in your answer, but I will study it more in depth tomorrow.

To me the most important part was using the CASE WHEN inside the SUM function. I looked for it, but I couldn't find it myself, so I'm very thankful that you were kind enough to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's better to add rows to result sets, rather than columns. The key is to get the data collect as you want it. The presentation is generally not a task SQL is suited for. With that in mind, I'd suggest that the output you *should* be attempting to get is this:

```
Table1id Month name    Table2  Table1
1        Sep   Text 1  400     500
1        Oct   Text 1  500     500
1        Nov   Text 1 
2        Sep   Text 1  
2        Oct   Text 1  900     800
2        Nov   Text 1 
3        Sep   Text 1  300     200
3        Oct   Text 2  200     200
3        Nov   Text 3  250     200
```

This is pretty trivial (I'm using Oracle syntax since you did not specify a database):

```
select table1id, 
       to_Date(to_date(table2.month||'01','YYYYMMDD'),'mmm') as Month, 
       table1.name, 
       table2.amount as table2, 
       table1.amount as table1 
from table2 
join table1 
on to_date(table2.month||'01','YYYYMMDD') <= table1.end
   and last_day(to_date(table2.month||'01','YYYYMMDD')) >= table1.end
   and table1.id = table2.table1id
```

Comment: Even though I ended up using a different solution to my problem, I would like to let you know that I appreciate that you took the time and made an effort to help me out.

Thank you!